# Wicket label + Ajax not working

Tags: java, ajax, label, wicket

I have a simple, mysterious problem with a label and using ajax to show it.

```
public class ChecklistTemplateForm extends Form{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Label cantSaveLabel;
    public ChecklistTemplateForm(String id) {
        super(id);
        cantSaveLabel = new Label("cantSaveLabel", "Name is not unique, enter another name and try saving again.");
        cantSaveLabel.setVisible(false);
        cantSaveLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(cantSaveLabel);
        add(new AjaxButton("saveButton") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.addComponent(cantSaveLabel);
                //here i do some stuff to decide if canSave is true or false
                if (canSave){
                    setResponsePage(AdminCheckListPage.class);
                }
                else if (!canSave){
                    cantSaveLabel.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println(canSave);
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

}
```

The funny thing is, is canSave is false, the System.out.print works but the cansavelabel never becomes visible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not update the Label via Ajax as it is not in the rendered page. The

```
cantSaveLabel.setVisible(false);
```

makes it so that the Label is not in the HTML. You would need to surround the Label with another component (WebMarkupContainer), call setOutputMarkupId(true) on this and add this container to the AjaxRequestTarget instaed of the label.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had no idea about this behaviour. I tried using a webmarkupcontainer without success though. There may be some other error in my code which prevents this from working. Also I realized now that since I will be using this panel for editing objects as well as creating new ones, demanding a unique name for all objects to save isnt the smartest idea.

Comment: @fred can you post some code with the WebMarkupContainer? Or is the isue resolved since you don 't need the behaviour anymore?

Comment: Sorry mate, late answer. Yes, unfortunately I will call this a wrap as the functionality is no longer needed. I appreciate your input and Im sorry I cant give you a more detailed example.

Answer (score 13):

You have to tell wicket that it should use a placeholder for you label because it can't update a component that doesn't exist in the markup.

```
cantSaveLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
cantSaveLabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for a solution. I wonder why Wicket does not automatically enable FLAG_PLACEHOLDER when _OUTPUT_MARKUP_ID is enabled?

Comment: I think the idea is to keep the HTML code as plain and simple as possible. By enabling this by default it can cause many unnecessary tags in your HTML. It's not really a big deal once you know it... ;)

Comment: `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag()` calls `setOutputMarkupId()`, so you don't need to call both.